# I am failing to clone a git repo when behind a proxy

Tags: networking, git

When I run `git clone git://git.gnome.org/tracker`, I get:

```
Cloning into tracker...
git.gnome.org[0: 209.132.180.173]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
```

This doesn't happen when I'm not behind a network proxy I'm currently at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the http version of git.gnome.org repo and set http_proxy environment variable

```
http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:proxy_port
git clone http://git.gnome.org/browse/tracker
```

you might also need to add the proxy to git config

```
git config --global http.proxy $http_proxy
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it would be extra nice to know how to do it with using the git protocol.

Comment: @Tshepang: See @Gilles thorough explanation. Nothing more to add there.

Answer (score 6):

Terminology note: the [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29) is what blocks you from connecting to some sites or ports directly. The [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) is an intermediate server that you can connect to (but not for everything) and that is allowed to access the Internet.

If your proxy isn't trying too hard to block non-web traffic, you may be able to get it to relay your git connection. Use a program like [corkscrew](http://freshmeat.net/projects/corkscrew) or [connect-proxy](http://www.taiyo.co.jp/~gotoh/ssh/connect.html) to use the [`CONNECT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) method to try and get through the proxy. Put something like this in your `~/.git/config` (replace `proxy.example.com` and 3128 by your proxy's host name and port):

```
[core]
gitProxy="corkscrew proxy.example.com 3128 git.gnome.org 9418"
```

Many proxies are configured to allow `CONNECT` only to port 443 (https), and they may check that the traffic they're relaying is actually SSL. If that's the case for you, as far as I know, your only options are to use a different protocol, use an external relay that you can reach (e.g. ssh tunnel with a server on port 443), or get your network administrator to allow git traffic.

Answer (score 1):

See **[git-config](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)** details, you can set proxies for HTTP or GIT protocols.