# I am failing to use XChat when behind a proxy

Tags: http-proxy, xchat

So I set my HTTP proxy via **Settings** -> **Preferences** -> **Network setup**, and am getting this error:

```
Looking up irc.us.gimp.org
Looking up <IP>
Connecting to <IP> (<IP>) port <PORT>...
HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow 
Proxy traversal failed.
Stopped previous connection attempt (pid=4696)
```

(`<IP>` and `<PORT>` are substitutions)

Without that setting (the IP:PORT is left empty), I'm getting this error:

```
Looking up irc.us.gimp.org
Connecting to irc.us.gimp.org (192.219.30.200) port 6667...
Connection failed. Error: Connection refused
```

Comment: [A few words on ISA Server](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Web-Browsing-Behind-ISA-Server-HOWTO.html#ss2.1)

Comment: [See this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9551/i-am-failing-to-clone-a-git-repo-when-behind-a-proxy/9589#9589). Your proxy doesn't allow `CONNECT` to port 6667, so you'll have to find an external relay.

Comment: @Gilles: If this comment was an answer, it could be accepted, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your failing to reach XChat through the proxy because your proxy is specifically set to deny you this privilege. Talk to whoever configures or maintains the proxy and see if they'll allow this.